# Is it possible to determine the impulse given to a coin during a coin flip?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Given that we assume the force acting on a coin as well as the distance the which force acts on the coin is constant, would it be possible to determine the linear impulse on the coin with only that information?

[image]

Comment: You would need to know the duration of the force in order to calculate the impulse.

Comment: so knowing the force itself would not allow you to find time?

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate the angular Impulse.. (analogous to Torque and Force, Angular Impulse and Impulse)..
If we consider a simple case in which we neglect Upward motion of coin.. we cal calculate the angular velocity
J = P X R
Here, J = m∆v*r

Comment: would it be possible to calculate linear impulse instead? Additionally, if I the change in velocity is unknown, how can we find the angular impulse?

Comment: I feel that if you knew how the coin was flipped (where it was struck with a linear force to start the flip) and know the angular impulse, then you can determine the linear force applied to produce that angular impulse and from that could also find you the linear impulse.